# R-Studio: Error message using exatcRLRT-function

Tags: r, rstudio, nlme

`Hi guys,

I´m quite new to R, but I still try my hand on a discontinuous growth modeling using nlme.
To test, if it makes sense to enter a random slope into the model, I´ve used the exactRLRT function, unfortunatly I´ve got the following Error: Error in matrix(unlist(value), nrow = nrow(data), dimnames = list(row.names(data),  :   length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

I cannot find any reasons, since the three compared models´ve worked well and all consist of a "List of 18" [from environment].

The ICC (1) with multilevel level package was significant.

I do not know, why it fails ...

I´m thankfull for any kind of help

AC`

```
model_var1_A <- lme(var_1 ~ time, random = list(PartID = pdDiag(~ time)), 
                   data = TEDdata.dgm, 
                   na.action = na.omit, 
                   control = list(opt = "optim")) 

model_var_1_O <- lme(var_1 ~ time, random =~ 1 | PartID, 
                   data = TEDdata.dgm,                                                             
                   na.action = na.omit, 
                   control = list(opt = "optim")) 
summary(model_var_1_O)


model_var_1_r <- lme(var_1 ~ time, random =~ 0 + time | PartID,
                   data = TEDdata.dgm, 
                   na.action = na.omit, 
                   control = list(opt = "optim"))
summary(model_var_1_r)

library (RLRsim)
exactRLRT(model_var_1_r, model_var_1_A, model_var_1_O)
```